# equivalent jquery css expression for given xpath?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an xpath

```
//tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[3]/b[1]/a[1]
```

and would like a Jquery equivalent css expression following this format:

```
tbody:eq(0)>tr:eq(0)>td:eq(2)>b:eq(0)>a:eq(0)
```

I expected `$("tbody:eq(0)>tr:eq(0)>td:eq(2)>b:eq(0)>a:eq(0)").length` to return a match but nothing is found.

neither does `$("tr:eq(0)>td:eq(2)>b:eq(0)>a:eq(0)").length` or `$("td:eq(2)>b:eq(0)>a:eq(0)").length` returns any match.

`$("b:eq(0)>a:eq(0)").length` however is found.

Why does the latter work but the former starting at `tr:eq(0)`, and `td:eq(2)`, doesn't work ?

Comment: You'll have to show the markup. I'm not saying we can't infer it from the xpath, but still, better safe than...

Comment: That should work, [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/Fj3Us/) . Considering you got the correct markup.

Comment: you are right, I was using a wrong html sample. that's why it wasn't selecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That translation of the XPath to a jQuery selector looks fine to me, and it seems to work:

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ifeha4)

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Zero <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>One <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>Two <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>Three <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>Four <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>Five <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zero <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>One <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>Two <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>Three <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>Four <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>Five <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zero <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>One <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>Two <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>Three <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>Four <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
      <td>Five <b>bold <a href='#'>link1</a> <a href='#'>link 2</a></b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
var match = $("tbody:eq(0)>tr:eq(0)>td:eq(2)>b:eq(0)>a:eq(0)");
alert("match.length = " + match.length);
match.css({
  "color": "red",
  "border": "1px solid black"
});
```

I get the alert that the match length is `1` (as expected), and the resulting highlighted link looks like the right one to me.

Comment: Side note: It's no shorter, but you can use `:first` instead of `:eq(0)` anywhere you think it may be clearer...